# Practical body armor for a female who can create objects from her body

Tags: super-powers, armors, clothing

In the anime [My Hero Academia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Hero_Academia), most people have a random ability like  a physical enhancement, a bodily mutation, control of an element, etc.

[Momo Yaoyorozu](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Momo_Yaoyorozu) is a student who has the ability to create any non-living material if she knows the molecular make-up of it by converting the fat-cells in her body. Most of her fat cells are located in the front-torso area (the chest and belly) so she finds that it is easier/faster to create objects from there. This is her current [hero costume](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e0/23/5e/e0235e6b242eb817276dfc7c4159a626.png), which doesn't seem very supportive or protective in the slightest.

I'm currently trying to think of a good future hero outfit for her for when she becomes a pro-hero, for a story I'm writing, but I'm cant think of anything that wouldn't sacrifice modesty over functionality.

An open back might work, but not for quick occasions. It would be awkward to try and grab larger items out of your back when you can't see and/or fighting someone in front of you. There would also be a slight delay, just like there is in her arms/legs. This would still be okay in many situations, but she also would need the ability to make something from her whole front in case of emergencies.

Zippers wouldn't really work because they might get stuck or pinch her skin if she's trying to fight in a hurry. And she'd need to zip it back up afterwards and her hands might be full of the object(s) she created.

She can also create new clothes to replace ones that she's ripped, but this uses energy and her body only has a limited number of fat cells. This would be too draining during long fights.

Any armor/costume ideas out there for decent protection, not flashing everyone, and allowing her to quickly make something using her whole torso?

Examples of items she's made:

- Full-sized cannon from full torso
- Shields from arms
- Reflective blanket from back
- Staffs from hands
- Bombs from belly
- Gas masks from chest

Comment: Why does a lady with a cannon need armor?  Does she need to get really close?  Is she a really bad shot?

Comment: @Willk The cannon used up most of her fat cells in her body, it was really for a specific case. She would probably end up in a lot of close-combat situations because many people have abilities that allow them to move themselves or projectiles quickly. She would need to be able to handle long distance and close combat for this reason. Unless she makes herself some sort of equipment that can move her fast away (like rocket powered skates, or a grappling hook) then she's pretty much a sitting duck.

Comment: If she can get the fat cells out of her body without having to open up her skin, why can she not get them through clothing as well?

Comment: Can she create armor in a blink of an eye? Can she go from bikini-clad to full armored when needed?

Comment: @user10915156 Create from fat cells, meaning the object literally rise out of her skin. She can't change it once it's out of her skin. I'm guessing you pushes the fat cells to the top layer of her skin and changes it there.

Comment: @Alexander Larger objects takes longer time as it requires more cells and more focus. I think to create a full armor for herself would take a long time and that would be a lot of material, ergo a lot of her fat cells. And if she became covered in armor, then she would have no skin left showing to produce objects form.

Comment: @Sensoray Oh, I see that she can't "recycle" her gear. Never mind then, my idea won't work.

Comment: I have *got* to submit a [Frame Challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7097).  This chick would need to eat the worst of all foods *constantly* to keep up the fat content of her body so she could make *anything.*  She'd be completely flat-chested because that's where most of the torso fat is in your slender-busty character.  And unless the item being made is small (to slip out of a sleeve or some such), her only option is to run around naked (although WillK's answer comes close).  This isn't a particularly practical superhero.

Comment: @JBH She does eat constantly. She comes from a rich family, so she can afford it.  I believe she can choose where she drains her fat cells from, so her boobs probably go last. Since she can manipulate her fat cells, I'm guessing that she probably shuffles them to her breasts. Easier to have big boobs than a big booty/belly. Harder to pull stuff outta your booty or fight with a disproportional belly.

Comment: @Sensoray :-) that last bit might be a man's perspective.  I believe it was comedian Bette Midler who once joked about jogging having the consequence of black eyes and bruised knees....

Comment: Hard to fight with disproportionate boobs, I know you're after a boob window here but she's better off pulling things out of her arse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm tricky, especially with modesty enabled. Useful areas include chest and belly - but also butt and thighs, which are less vital. Should probably make use of these fat cells for trasformation in high-risk situations, as it lessens exposure of the more vulnerable torso. Consider an armoured knee-length skirt with armoured stockings. In most positions, that should cover all of her legs from attack, but any items she creates would fall down/be immediately reachable. If she wants to see what she's doing, she can pull the skirt up. Or there's always assless chaps, or some of the hiking pants that have an openable flap over the ass?

Actually, flaps are probably a great idea here - something detachable that you can yank down or off. If the universe has any fabric/flexible armour options (as opposed to metal or strong kevlar) that would be awesome. Have a tunic type arrangement where the front portion is a separate piece of fabric, held on with velcro - or like you suggested, magnets for a nice click back into place. If this is sewn on at the neck, it will remain permanently attached instead of being discarded and needing replacement every battle, avoiding extra work for her :)

In a fight, she can easily rip this off to gain access to her chest if she needs more material than available on her legs. You can either have a bra/undershirt to further protect her modesty, or decide that in that case, fuckit.

Comment: Your right, the thighs are a decent area for fat cells. The knee-length skirt idea is good, perhaps with a layered slit so she doesn't have to lift up her skirt but could still slip her hand in and access it without losing protection/mobility. A sports bra wouldn't work because it would cover the middle of the chest, I like the idea of a detachable piece with velcro, because she could have the hard part on her outfit and the soft part on the detachable piece and essentially raise and fit the new piece into the spot it was removed from.

Comment: However, I'd really not like here to have to create new pieces as this could be a huge waste of her limited fat resources to possible have to create multiple new chest pieces in battle. Her main focus in battle should be on preventing citizen casualties and detaining the enemy, not on her modesty. (Even though she would like to preserve it)

Comment: To avoid replication, sew it on along the neckline and Velcro the edges. Then can lever it up/across for access, but stays attached (and preserves more modesty)

Comment: Great Idea! That will WORK. And actually, the more I think about it, the more I think that instead of velcro, magnets could work instead. More of a solid "snap" back into place. I'll use this, thank you. If you update your answer to include what we discussed, I'll mark it as correct ^-^

Comment: Added! Glad it helped 

Answer (score 3):

## Take a page from clothes for breastfeeding mamas

[image]

Full modesty, easy access.  Use stretch materials and you can get to the breasts, chest, and upper belly without any trouble at all.

For the lower belly, a simple elastic waist pair of pants or shorts or skirt will do the trick.  Along with a top that you don't tuck in.

I vote for a skirt so she can easily access items made from her thighs and bottom.

Perhaps something like this, only with a breastfeeding-style top instead of the opening at the collarbone.

[image]

Perhaps with a skirt slightly longer and more flared?

[image]

To make these choices more protective, you can use light metal mesh or chainmail over parts of the fabric to protect against moderate blows.  A helm when needed wouldn't interfere with her powers.  You might also include a protective metal mesh dickie.

[image]

Comment: ahh i really like the idea of the top, I bet they could create a super stretchy material that would allow her to pull down the under portion to her belly as well. Top portion could stretch, but I'm still iffy on her flashing everyone and showing a breast. The neck mesh would be handy as well as it could still move and give her the ability to pull things out from under, but also protect her upper vitals +1

Comment: @Sensoray since there is a flap of material over the chest, she could reach under it, grab whatever she created from her breast and pull it down, then out.  This could be very quick and not expose her breast at all.

Comment: Love this idea, but since she can make whatever materials she wants I say scratch the chainmail and go for graphene interlaced with carbon nanofibers.  Does not take much to turn her lightweight maternity wear into light weight class-4 body armor.

Comment: @Nosajimiki perfect.  She can make them ahead of time too so she doesn't use up her energy and powers during the battle.

Answer (score 2):

**Muumuu**

[image: muumuu]

https://rachelherrick.wordpress.com/tag/fashion/

This outfit is probably not going to have viewers pausing the show, but it is perfect for your application.  It is the only thing she has on, but it is modest unless there is a strong updraft.    Skin underneath is all available for making objects.  Opponents will not see what she has made because they will be under the muumuu on her skin (for example, a Kevlar vest) - so the element of surprise.

Things she needs to pick up will fall out from under the muumuu.  She can practice kicking stuff up and catching it.

Plus it is cool in the summer.

Comment: +1 for body diversity in superheroes.

Comment: creative idea, but for large items, I think it would break through the dress or be hard to get out from under. If she created a grenade launcher and it dropped down, it's a pretty long item and it would be hard to maneuver it out from under her muumuu.

Comment: @Sensoray - too true, too true.  Muumuu must be very stretchy, and to obtain necessary clearance she needs to always walk on stilts.

Comment: @Sensoray - for maneuvering a longer item out, easiest would be to walk forward (or back) to let the item angle itself out as it falls.  Less fun than stilts, but easier, even if it takes another step or two to get back to grabbing range.

Answer (score 0):

During rest time, she could create a full-body armadillo-like plate armor and some clip-on bands to affix it to her body using her power. Mid-fight she can simply tear off plates as required to create objects then reattach them, only needing to regrow the clip-on part. In an emergency she can grow new ones and it can easily be adapted for various situation (smooth to swim, thick and soft to cushion blows, hard to defend against blades, kevlar against bullets, etc).